# How to pass an array variable to a controller?

Tags: codeigniter

I need to pass an array variable from a form to a controller in order to save the value to a database.

This is the view:

```
    <?php
            $i=1;

            foreach ($data->result() as $dt)  
            {                                                                               
            ?>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $i;?>" />
            <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" value="<?php echo   $name;?>" />
            <?php
            $i++;
            }
            ?>

<button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-mini btn-info"><i class="icon-save"></i>Save</button>​
```

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#save").click(function(){

    var string = $("#my-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/the_site/site_value/save_name",
        data    : string,
        cache   : false,
        success : function(data){
            $.gritter.add({
                title: 'Info..!!',
                text: data,
                class_name: 'gritter-info'
            });
        }
    });

});

});
```

​This is the controller:

```
public function save_name()
{
        $name = $this->input->post('name');//actually 'name' is 'name[]' from view.

        if (is_array($name))
        {
            foreach ($name as $name1 => $name2)
            {
                  $dt['person_name']     = $name2;
              }
          }

          $id['id_person'] = '001'; //this is just an example of id..
```

choose a table and its selected row...

```
 $q = $this->db->get_where("the_table",$id); 
        $row = $q->num_rows();
        if($row>0)
        {
```

Comment: continued:..{
                $this->db->update('the_table',$dt,$id);
                echo "Name successfully updated";
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->insert('the_table',$dt);
                echo "Name successfully saved";
            }
        
    }

Comment: *typo, in the view i meant was: $dt->name;, instead of $name

Comment: Please edit your question adding the comments above to it and explain what it is you are experiencing as an error. Start first with adding a var dump of name. Comments aren't for additional code blocks.

Comment: I also expect it has something to do with serialization in the Ajax call, so I don't expect you are getting an array at all (Ajax isn't my Forte)

Comment: thanks Alex, no notice errors came up, only nothing value inserted into table...I usually nothing problem with this: in a cotroller: $var=$this->input->post('var'), but when that variable  is an array variable which is from the view is like this: <input type="text" name="var[]" value="<php echo $dt->var;">  , my problem is I could not pass this array variable to controller, and absolutely we cannt do it with just like this: $var=$this->post('var').

Comment: what do you meant with serialization for array variables?, by serialization is working with many or some variables per single value, but how serialization for many/some variables which are not single value but an array value?

Comment: Title, grammar, code formatting

Comment: You can't save an array into the database. You can serialize the array and save it to the database, but I don't think that is what you want. I'm sorry but it is *very* hard to understand what you want to accomplish. Please update your question with the *full* controller function!

Answer (score 0):

The names array looks something like this when it is posted (I used `microtime()` to generate some random names just for an example):

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.33037500 1512871675
            [1] => 0.33040300 1512871675
            [2] => 0.33041700 1512871675
            [3] => 0.33043000 1512871675
            [4] => 0.33044300 1512871675
            [5] => 0.33045500 1512871675
            [6] => 0.33046800 1512871675
            [7] => 0.33048000 1512871675
            [8] => 0.33049100 1512871675
            [9] => 0.33050500 1512871675
            [10] => 0.33051700 1512871675
        )

)
```

You access the array like so: `$names = $this->input->post('name');` (which you already are doing).

Then you can run a foreach:

```
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $q = $this->db->get_where("the_table", array('name' => $name));
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->db->update('the_table', array('name' => $name), array('id' => $q->row()->id));
        echo "Name successfully updated";
    } else {
        $this->db->insert('the_table', array('name' => $name));
        echo "Name successfully saved";
    }
}
```

Each name you have to check if it exists. As you only variable to compare with is `name` you have to `get_where` name is the same. If it doesn't exist, you insert, if it does, you update with the given `id`. I *highly* suggest you read the [query builder documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) because you are passing strings instead of arrays directly in to the db functions. This will not work.

Comment: No activity. OK

Comment: dear Alex, thanks for the answer, it's working only the script from you, but the script from me was not working at all, I tried to change this:Array ( [name] => Array( [5] => 0.33045500 1512871675  WITH some kind like this:  $name=array();for ($i = 0; $i++) { foreach($query->result() as $dt) { $name[$i] = array()=>$dt[another_field]; } What is a solution for this problem, I mean how to store multiple rows (as another query from another table) into array var called 'name' ???

Comment: You just need the $names = $this->input->post('name'); and the foreach loop. My array was just an example of what an array post data for a field looks like. Your whole goal here is to post a field named name[] that makes an array and to process that array and either add or update correct?

Comment: The names array looks something like this when it is posted from the view:  <?php 
                $i=1;
                foreach ($data->result() as $dt)  
                {               
                                                                                         
                ?>  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name[]" value="<?php echo $dt->name;?>" />  well...as a novice this is nearly a month i m overwhelming about this case, i couldn't solve this till this day.

Comment: I get that, I mean `print_r($name)` after `$name = $this->input->post('name');` because you 100% should be getting an array in the form of what I am getting unless you messed something else up

Comment: it results bolean (false) when I put var_dump to test that, that's mean: when I post a var which is  "name[]"  this is not an array read by the controller, although it is arrray in view...

Comment: In you save_name function remove *everything* and make it look *exactly* like this: `public function save_name() {
        
        $names = $this->input->post('name');
        print_r($names);
        exit;
        
    }`

Comment: In your ajax success function *remove everything* and do `console.log(data)` and report the console log here that is shown in chrome dev tools under console tab

Comment: there are two: (1):  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined
    at jquery.flot.resize.min.js:19
    at jquery.flot.resize.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ jquery.flot.resize.min.js:19
(anonymous) @ jquery.flot.resize.min.js:19

Comment: and this (2) :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at e.fn.init.domManip (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5)
    at e.fn.init.append (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5)
    at e.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5)
    at Function.access (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at e.fn.init.html (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:5)
    at Object.success (isi_nilai:512)
    at l (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4)

Comment: what does those log tell?, I m looking forward for the explanation dear Alex...for this I really appreciate so much.. Btw I did print_r or var_dump but the notification is the array from view (name[]) was boolean false.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Even if those errors were halting Ajax from running you wouldn't get a response when you submitted. I can't figure out what's happening here.

Comment: thanks for all the concerns from you so far, it's really encouriging and helpfull, now i can figure it out.